# how to show image after the page is completely loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have image which needs to show up after the page is completely loaded below is sample of the code any help will be appreciated

```
<div id="playbutton">
<img style="width: 200px; height: 200px; border: 0;" src="http://iconshots.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/final1.jpg">

</div>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onload

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hide the image to begin with; `style="display:none;` or a `css` class with this rule is fine. Then wait for **DOM and all graphics (images) to load**, then show the image:

**HTML**

```
<div id="playbutton">
<img style="width: 200px; height: 200px; border: 0;display:none;" src="http://iconshots.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/final1.jpg">

</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(window).load(function() {
  $('#playbutton img').show();
});
```

Comment: i tried it but it's not working here is http://jsfiddle.net/cwL9moqk/7/

Comment: Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/cwL9moqk/9/

Comment: Great! You're welcome. ... sorry I took out your onclick code by mistake .. put it back ..  `onclick="this.style.display='none';"`  `http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/cwL9moqk/10/`

Comment: Don't forget accept and vote for the answer.

Comment: but the other option is not working  seems like you removed this code  onclick="this.style.display='none'; and it started working but how can i make it work with both of the codes?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/cwL9moqk/10/

Comment: okay so i tried adding the code full page it didn't work its working fine on original fiddle but it's not working if i reuse the code so i made another fiddle and its not working am i doing something wrong? am i missing something i used the same original codes :((( i got headache can you please help thanks sorry im new to this http://jsfiddle.net/y4nbpd66/

Comment: 1. You did not include jQuery. 2. You left the setting at `onLoad`. Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/y4nbpd66/1/

Comment: do you have direct link for the javascript?

Comment: it was driving me nuts i was like i did everything right but what did i miss i was going back and fourth learning by mistakes i guess :)

Comment: It's all there in the page source: `<script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js'></script>`

Comment: awesome thanks for your help and sorry for asking to many questions :) you have been life saver thank thank thank thank you soo much :))

Answer (score 0):

you can set its display property to none

```
<img id='hiddenImage' style="display:none; width: 200px; height: 200px; border: 0;" src="http://iconshots.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/final1.jpg">
```

and change it with jquery when the page is loaded

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#hiddenImage').show();
});
```

Comment: i tried it but it's not working here is http://jsfiddle.net/cwL9moqk/7/